# How do I make hidden files in windows 10 opaque

Tags: windows, file, registry, explorer, appdata

Normally when you turn on view hidden files, the hidden files will be semi-transparent. Is there a way to make them full opacity? Specifically, I'm looking to make my appdata folder fully visible.

Answer (score 0):

> $TargetDirectory = "$env:UserProfile\AppData"
> (Get-Item $TargetDirectory -Force).Attributes = 'Directory, NotContentIndexed'
>
> We delete the Hidden attribute.